# Sort a queryset by related model field and some operations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have 3 models as follows:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Thread(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to get: 
1- most active topics in this week by number of new messages 
2- most active topics by most recent messages

**Note:** I have solved this challenge by getting the QuerySet and sorting it with python code. I want to know if there is a way to do the same with django ORM.

Comment: What is the difference b/w 1 and 2?

Comment: @JPG Maybe topic 1 got 100 messages in Saturday but topic 2 got last message yesterday. So in 1, topic 1 is first, in 2, topic 2 is first.